# Port forwarding ok but not able to access data

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, portforwarding

I have forwarded the ports from my modem and while checking from "canyouseeme.org" it says,

```
Success: I can see your service on 1.186.*.* on port (8510) `Your ISP is not blocking port 8510.
```

But when I access my files the browser responds as,

```
This webpage is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Hide details
Google Chrome's connection attempt to 1.186.*.* was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured.
```

I have put my wamp server online,changed port to 8510,set "Allow from all" in the httpd.conf but everything in vain.Can anyone help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you putting the port in your browser? http://1.186.123.123:8510

Comment: yes, in the address bar.

Comment: without the port it gives, Object Not found, The requested URL '/index.php' was not found on the RomPager server.

Comment: localhost:8510 works ?

Comment: Let me be more specific what I have done, I have separate modem and router. In the modem's port forwarding I assigned ports to the router's IP. And in the router's port forwarding link I assigned My laptop's IP.

Comment: yes, localhost:8510 as well as 192.168.2.101:8510 works

Comment: how about removing the router from the equation for a test. Not sure why you are messing with the ports on WAMP honestly. From the outside, I can see why 80 coming in might be bad, for instance if you want like apache to grab that or whatever. But from the outside on 8510, going to laptop on 80, why not just leave that be ? Outside to 8510 -> wamp IP:80  Reduce the moving parts

Comment: I tried the same, directly connected the laptop with a lan cable on the modem, but I got the same result.
I have changed the wamp's port to 8510 though.

Comment: well when you go laptop to modem, your DHCP is gonna be different. It's the router that makes it `.101`

Comment: Yes, during that, I had set the port forwarding to my laptops Lan IP(192.168.1.3) and when connected to router (192.168.1.2)  it was set as (192.168.2.101)

Comment: sometimes one has to do a MAC clone. Often it takes an hour and a manual download of a pdf or google to figure these things out, modem model # specific. If directly to modem is not working, I would definitely remove the router from the soup first. I feel for ya, it is a miserable process

Comment: Okay, I shall give a try on MAC clone then and pop out the router from the scene. Thanks @Drew  for the guide. I will get back once done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might either face a configuration problem with all your forwards, or - the most common reason for this behaviour - your router does not support *Loopback-Connections*.

Meaning: Even IF your external ip would be 1.1.1.1 - calling 1.1.1.1 from within your local network does not work, because your router is unable to determine that 1.1.1.1 refers to itself on the WAN-side. (or it forwards all connections on the *external* ip to its *internal* ip, therefore failing for machines behind the router which rely on port-forwarding to be executed, which does not happen for requrests arriving on the *internal* ip adress.)

don't be afraid, only very little routers are supporting this. Even if you use an external dynamic dns, you usually can't connect from *withing your local network*. To verify whether this is the case or *not* - you need to move physicaly outside to check connectivity (or use a thethered connection with internet-Sharing on your mobile and connect through your smartphone, tablet or notebook using the internet sharing feature)

If *canyouseeme.org* can *see* you - but you can't from your local network I'll bet, you are running in exactly this issue.

Edit: I'm having the exact same Problem. (well not a problem, if you know about):

**CanYouSeeMee**

[image]

**Local Network:**

[image]

**Smartphone (Wifi Disconnected)**

[image]

Sidenode: To have everything like owncloud working internally as well, I just configured my DNS-Server to serve a *fake* Forward-Lookup, so that `http://externaldomain.com` is resolved as an *local ip* from inside my network.

So, from outside: `http://externaldomain.com` resoles to whatever my external ip is (`91.48.*.*)` but from the inside, it resolves to the internal ip of the very same server (`192.168.5.5`).

So, I could use all DNS-Names without limitation, only can't use my external ip.

Comment: just use your smartphone

Comment: when I call my external ip, it redirects to my modem's login page. Is it that I need to get access from outside network.

Comment: yes, canyouseeme.org can see me and responds your ISP is not blocking port 8510 as well as 3306.

Comment: the redirect:8510 should not be going to your modem's login page

Comment: yes, without the port, i mean just the IP redirects.

Comment: No - then your modem *catches* the request to the *External* ip (WAN) and redirects it to the modems internal ip (LAN) which is the problem. Therefore, whenever you try to contact `http://externalip/page`, the modem will catch it and forward it to `http://internalip/page` - which does not exist on the modem itself.

Comment: then it begs the question, what **firewall** changes were made on wamp box to permit success. The modem acts as a proxy for 8510 (meaning it accepts the socket connect). That is why canyouseeme says what it says. Thereafter it dies. It dies because the laptop forbids connects to 8510

Comment: @Drew: I had set the ServerName with my internal ip, Allow from all and changed the port to 8510 in the apache's httpd.conf file. Can you guide where shall I make the firewall changes on wamp.

Comment: do you have a smartphone / mobile available? If so, please disconnect your wifi and try to contact your target address. Are you seeing the modems logon page, nothing or the page desired?

Comment: without the port, it asks for the same login and password of my modem.

Comment: Hurray ! and with the port assigned, it displayed my index page.

Comment: @Drew ~ you saved my night ! I had set the firewall rule, might be that worked...

Comment: @dognose "you usually can't connect from withing your local network. To verify whether this is the case or not - you need to move physicaly outside to check connectivity" - You are my saviour!!

Answer (score 1):

Change laptop firewall to allow inbound connections to port 8510.

[Open a Port in Windows Firewall](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-port-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7)

This can be very broad, as firewall layers can including many components, such as those from Norton, etc.